# R -Multiple conditional matching in a string

Tags: regex, r

Is there a better way to do a string conditional match? for example the word **farm** is conditionally matched with **rose**, **floral** and **tree**. ideally I would like to do the matching without repeating **farm**

```
str = c('rose','farm','rose farm','floral', 'farm floral', 'tree farm')
grep("((?=.*farm)(?=.*rose)|(?=.*farm)(?=.*floral)|(?=.*farm)(?=.*tree))", str, value = TRUE,,perl = TRUE)
```

this return

```
[1] "rose farm"   "farm floral" "tree farm"
```

Comment: you can get it with this `grep(' ', str, value = TRUE)` might not be that helpful though

Answer (score 4):

One way — use a grouping construct to combine the set of words:

```
grep('(?=.*farm)(?=.*(?:rose|floral|tree))', str, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "rose farm"   "farm floral" "tree farm"
```